# Parse Dates from column within Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to parse the date from the column and add a column with the weekday. However, I am very new to python and programming in general. The

```py
date_parse = pd.read_csv(input_file, parse_cols = "Date")
```

gives me an error. My goal was to parse the data from the column "Date" of the pandas dataset and and save it as `date_parse`, so I could then convert it with `date.weekday`. It didn't like the `parse_cols`. I'm not sure if I'm even closely doing this correctly or if I'm way off base. I've been working on this for about a week and no cookie. So I broke down and decided to ask here. I suspect that `pd.read` is maybe for Excel only? Any tips?

```
Error:
Exception has occurred: TypeError
read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parse_cols'
  File "input_file", line 21, in <module>
    date_parse = pd.read_csv(input_file, parse_cols = "Date")
```

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import csv
import datetime as dt
import calendar

#Added input_file to make is easier than copying the file path everywhere
input_file = "BrkHist.csv"

#Pulling information from yahoo
brk = yf.Ticker("brk-B")
brk.info
Hist_data = brk.history(period="2y")
Hist_data.to_csv(input_file)

#Change csv file to pandas
data = pd.read_csv(BrkHist.csv)
#Select which columns I want to see on the dataframe
brkp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Date','Weekday','Open','Close'])
#Parse data from date column
date_parse = pd.read_csv(input_file, parse_cols = "Date")
print(date_parse)
#Add Weekday column to hold days of the week data in integer form
dp_weekday = date(date_parse).weekday()
#Convert weekday column data into string value
days = {0:'Monday',1:'Tuesday',2:'Wednesday',3:'Thursday',4:'Friday',5:'Saturday',6:'Sunday'}
#Add day of week column with new data
data.insert (1, "Weekday"[dp_weekday])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas read csv has no parse_cols keyword (see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).
Did you mean to use `parse_dates=['Date']` ?

Comment: I think that was it! You have me at my next step in my code. Thank you. I borrowed the code from somewhere else out, but I think it was from an excel thing. I was trying everything before I came on here to ask questions. I'm still going through courses online to figure out how to apply python code. For example how to understand the () and when something has a .

Comment: you are welcome, happy to help! If this answer worked for you could you please accept it and close the thread :)